# How to make the selected values bind to the form in angular8

Tags: javascript, angular

Initially in ngOnInit() i have given the first list value to be binded to the form, so the first value is filled to the form but the right hand side first item is not selected, i mean even the first row value is selected it doesnt highlight the first item in the row, but if i click on that it gets active/highlighted with active class added to the particular row.
When i click on other items, it doesnt change that row value to the form, it still remains to be in the first row values even though the second row is clicked.
When i click on add new, even then the empty values are not getting binded, by pushing the rows in right hand side to bottom.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue or give me suggestions like where i am going wrong so i can work on the wrong approached side.

DEMO:
[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ck3u8u-pwkt6s?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

TS:(Parent Component)

```
public selectedUser(data) {
  this.userDetails = data;
  this.userInitial = true;
  }


  public addNewButton() {
    this.userList = [{"Id": 0,
        "agentCode": 1205,
        "userName": 'addNewButton',
        "firstName": "new",
        "middleName": '',
        "lastName": '2',
        "department": 'New department1',
  }]
     this.userDetails = this.userList[0]
  }
```

HTML:(Parent component)

```
 <app-user-table [userDetails]="userDetails" (goListingPage)="showUserDetails($event)" ></app-user-table>

<div class="col-4">
        <div class="nav nav-pills vertical-tabs flex-column scrollable" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist"
            aria-orientation="vertical" *ngIf="userList && userList?.length > 0">
            <a class="nav-link" id="user_{{user.Id}}" data-toggle="pill" href="#tab-user_{{user.Id}}" role="tab"
                aria-controls="tab-user_1" aria-selected="true" *ngFor="let user of userList" (click)="selectedUser(user)">
                <h6 class="font-weight-bold"><span>{{user.firstName}}</span>
                    <span>{{user.lastName}}</span></h6>
                <span class="d-block font-sm">{{user.department}}</span>
                <span class="d-block font-sm">{{user.title}}</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So from demo, I am expecting for first row to be highlighted like as it appears when selected and that first value to be shown, then when click on add new button new value to be binded to the form by pushing the right hand side rows below the new row, like it must appears as if user is adding new form, and he is already having few records. When click on 2nd row, we should be able to see 2nd row details .

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how you can do it:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ck3u8u-wns7vr

But I would really recommend you to have a look at the angular tour of heroes (https://angular.io/tutorial) and check how the routing works using `[routerLink]` and `[routerLinkActive]`. If you use those and opt out of the bootstrap routing, the highlighting will work out of the box and all the extra code, that will be explained below, will not be needed.

But to the Solution of your current Problem:

To push your new Users to the top of the list, change

```
  public addNewButton() {
    this.userList = [{"Id": 0,
        "agentCode": 1205,
        "userName": 'addNewButton',
        "firstName": "new",
        "middleName": '',
        "lastName": '2',
        "department": 'New department1',
  }]
     this.userDetails = this.userList[0]
  }
```

to

```
  public addNewButton() {
    this.userList = [{"Id": 0,
        "agentCode": 1205,
        "userName": 'addNewButton',
        "firstName": "new",
        "middleName": '',
        "lastName": '2',
        "department": 'New department1',
  }, ...this.userList]
     this.userDetails = this.userList[0]
  }
```

This will prepend to the item to you already existing list.

Next we want to tackle the problem of highlighting the first item on load and new items after they were created on a button click.
For this we need to select the anchors of your right list as ViewChildren. Sadly it is not possible to select html native elements as ViewChildren, so we create a dummy directive that is applied to the anchors and can be selected using ViewChildren.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appSelectableAnchor]'
})
export class SelectableAnchorDirective {

  constructor(
    private elementRef: ElementRef<HTMLAnchorElement>
  ) { }

  public removeBootstrapActive() {
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.classList.remove('active');
  }

  public setBootstrapActive() {
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.classList.add('active');
  }
}
```

this directive is then applied to the anchors in `app.component.html`

```
            <a class="nav-link" id="user_{{user.Id}}" data-toggle="pill" href="#tab-user_{{user.Id}}" role="tab"
                aria-controls="tab-user_1" aria-selected="true" *ngFor="let user of userList" (click)="selectedUser(user)" appSelectableAnchor>
```

Now we are able to select the anchors as ViewChildren in app.component.ts

```
 @ViewChildren(SelectableAnchorDirective) selectableUsers: QueryList<SelectableAnchorDirective>;
```

To select the first one after load, we check the ViewChildren in ngAfterViewInit (in ngOnInit it is not guaranteed, that the ViewChildren are already loaded) if the are some, we select the first.

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (this.selectableUsers.length > 0) {
      this.selectableUsers.first.setBootstrapActive();
    }
  }
```

To do the same when a new user is added, we need to run a change detection cycle to after the user has been added to the list, so that the ViewChildren are updated. After that we can highlight the new item in the same matter as in ngAfterViewInit.

For some reason the active class lingers on if a new Item is inserted. So we remove it manually, before adding a new user. All in all the `addNewButton` method looks like this:

```
  public addNewButton() {
    if (this.selectableUsers.length > 0) {
      this.selectableUsers.first.removeBootstrapActive();
    }
    this.userList = [{"Id": 0,
        "agentCode": 1205,
        "userName": 'addNewButton',
        "firstName": "new",
        "middleName": '',
        "lastName": '2',
        "department": 'New department1',
  }, ...this.userList]
     this.userDetails = this.userList[0]
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
    if (this.selectableUsers.length > 0) {
      this.selectableUsers.first.setBootstrapActive();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is working as expected in demo, but when i click on add new, the focus must be on the new item, but here the active is on both the selected row and the newly got row

Comment: i mean, i clickeed on 2nd row and clicked on add new, so the focus been went for both first row(i.e) newly added row and the previous selected row